# Вопрос про области видимости переменных

Tags: java, область-видимости, variable

```
@Override
String toHex(String filepath) {
    try {
        FileReader readFile = new FileReader(filepath);
        BufferedReader readBuffer = new BufferedReader(readFile);
    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("Input output error: " + error);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Есть такой блок кода, я понимаю на данном этапе он выглядит безсмысленно, но вопрос возник именно в нем. Понимаю вопрос может показаться крайне тривиальным, но **как использовать `readFile` или `readBuffer` вне блока `try...catch`?** 
*UPD: без использования `throws`*

Comment: `FileReader readFile = null; try { ... } catch { ... } readFile.doSomething();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем вы собираетесь использовать код с потенциально возможным исключением вне try/catch конструкции? Как минимум у вас будет чрезмерно громоздкий код там, где он совсем ненужен.

Вот, на мой взгляд, оптимальное использование приведённого вами кода.

```
@Override
String toHex(String filepath)
{
    try (BufferedReader readBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)))
    {
        return readBuffer.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while loading file: " + error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

И не используйте специфические инстансы исключений там, где не уверены в определённости исключения. В итоге с вашим IOException вы после голову сломаете в попытках понять почему код не работает, если исключение будет иным из-за неправильной логики обработки внутри конструкции.

Answer (score 1):

№1

использовать `throws IOException` при создании метода

```
public void my_coord(String Coord) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("coord.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);           
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("coord.txt")));
```

№2

не совсем, без try, но зато без catch

```
public void inz(String name) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
    } finally {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

работая с записью-чтением, нельзя полностью отказаться от try-catch. либо вы это укажите при создании метода, либо в его "внутренностях".